# PHP FPM processes opening a ton of files and leaving them open

Tags: linux, apache, php

I'm finding that my PHP FPM processes are opening a ton of files, so many that I'm bumping up against OS limits causing my FPM processes to die. I'm assuming that this is caused by memory leaky PHP apps that are crashing and these connections not severing? What sort of config options would be best for me to focus on in turning over new connections and closing files so that I'm dealing with this more gracefully and don't have to use the emergency threshold limit or rely on Monit to automatically reload PHP FPM?

Answer (score 0):

Try mailing list http://php-fpm.org/community/

Answer (score 0):

My problem seems to have been my PHP-APC cache not being set high enough as to serve requests from memory.